# What are these commands used in the following section when using the libxl library?

Tags: excel, linux, libxl

[It's from the readme section on how to use libxl when I downloaded it and started using it in mingw-w64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei9YW.png)

- What is the use of `-I` in this command?
- What is the use of `-L` in this command?
- What is the use of `-lxl` in this command?

I can't figure out what they mean and what they do; can anyone help me?

This is an example taken from the library libxl readme section.

Answer (score 0):

This is a command to invoke Gnu's C++ compiler on the 'generate.cpp' source code file to create an executable named generate.exe.

`-I../../../include.cpp` says to look 3 directories above the current one for an Include file named include.cpp.

`-lxl` says to search the "xl" library when the linking loader runs and `-L../../../bin` says you might find the "xl" library in the bin folder three levels above the current directory

Comment: what is the use of the include file?

Comment: If you have ever programmed in C or C++, every library of function/ subroutine calls has a corresponding  Include file that declares each function, its parameters and their variable types, and the type of value returned by the function.  It is usually referenced near the top of the source code itself with a `#include <filename>` directive,